# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io

When I execute the code below, I get the common exception `The process cannot access the file *filePath* because it is being used by another process`.

What is the most efficient way to allow this thread to wait until it can safely access this file?

Assumptions:

- the file has just been created by me, so it is unlikely that another app is accessing it.
- more than one thread from my app might be trying to run this code to append text to the file.

:

```
 using (var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Append)) //Exception here
 {
     using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
     {
         sw.WriteLine(text);
     }
 }
```

So far, the best that I have come up with is the following. Are there any downsides to doing this?

```
    private static void WriteToFile(string filePath, string text, int retries)
    {
        const int maxRetries = 10;
        try
        {
            using (var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Append))
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            if (retries < maxRetries)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                WriteToFile(filePath, text, retries + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Max retries reached.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple threads attempting to access the same file, consider using a locking mechanism. The simplest form could be:

```
lock(someSharedObject)
{
    using (var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Append)) //Exception here
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative, consider:

```
File.AppendText(text);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set a [`FileShare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) to allow multiple access with this [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx) command like

```
File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

But i think the cleanest way if you have multiple threads that are trying to write into one file would be to put all these messages into a [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) and have one additional thread that writes all elements of the queue into the file.

Comment: in my case, this is still throwing the same exception. do I miss something?

Comment: @MauroBilotti: Are you sure, your process is the only one accessing the file?

Comment: Oliver, it works, the fact was that I had to change file access in 'read' mode because I was opening it that way. Thanks! I'll upvote you